# Routing in nginx URI with same prefix as another URI

Tags: nginx

Currently trying to use Nginx as a proxy and finding some difficulties with routes having another URI as a prefix. Example :

```
location /api/route/to/specific/application {
  proxy_pass http://proxying.to/site/A;
}

location /api {
  proxy_pass http://proxying.to/another/site/B;
}
```

When visiting http://mysite.io/api/route/to/specific/application, I get a **404 from Nginx** while when I visit  http://proxying.to/site/A directly I get the expected page.

Any idea how I can make it work ?

Thanks

Comment: What you've got and what did you expect?

Comment: I've got a 404. I'm expecting to see a blank page and have some logs (which I have when visiting directly the URI). I'm updating the question

Comment: What url did you request and what url you had on `proxing.to` server? Have you read nginx docs on `proxy_pass` and how it is works with paths?

Comment: there is no such option as `proxing.to` in the config file. I've read it couple of times. I hope not to miss something in it.

Comment: It's the server name you your wrote in your `proxy_pass` directive above. What request did that server got?

Comment: it's actually not the server name in the proxy_pass. Since I'm using Docker containers, I can specify a "name" for each container and link them accordingly to my needs. What is written down there is the container "name" which corresponds to something like 127.1.2.41. and that "server" unfortunatly didn't get any request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122493/discussion-between-alexey-ten-and-ismah).